# In "Default Config" store view, it still shows option of 'Use system Value'

Tags: magento2, store-view, system-configuration

I have installed magento 2 in my local machine. I think there is any problem in my installation because when I tap to Settings -> System -> Configuration and selected my store view as "**Default Config**". It shows as below image[image]:

Please tell me is it correct or I have made any mistake while installation?
Also let me know the solution if I am wrong.

Comment: Anyone else, who has faced this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with your installation, this is new since Magento 2.1 I think.

If that box is checked, the config value is taken from the module config.xml file corresponding to the system config section. In this case:

```
/vendor/magento/module-directory/etc/config.xml
```

See country default:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
<default>
...
    <general>
        <country>
            <optional_zip_countries>HK,IE,MO,PA,GB</optional_zip_countries>
            <default>US</default>
        </country>
    </general>
...
</default>
</config>
```